# how can i assign percentage height to a drop down (select) using css

Tags: html, css

i've a problem with styling a select with percentage values in height unlike inputs and textareas as it doesn't affect by the height.

my styles as following :

```
select {
    height:15%;
    width:100%;
    padding:5%;
    font-size:28px;
    color:#595959;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

it only affects by width, font, color, border radius and border ... height and padding as they don't exist.

anyone can help me with that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your CSS in a `<script>` element in your HTML?

Comment: Your CSS seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uDrDw/

Comment: The height of a select element is driven by the fontsize, I wish I could point to a more technical explanation (I'm sure someone else here can), I think it has something to do with being an inline element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply height you can apply it only through js once the elements are loaded.

Applying height through css will not work when page is loading

Comment: i already did, but it's only working with the existing select tags, unfortunately i'm loading my select tags from a web service ... so any ideas?